# Cannot serve images from express server to angular 2

Tags: angular, express, server

I have the express server configured using an express generator.

I have this line in express:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

Also in the angular code, I have this:

```
img src="/images/pic.png".
```

The image is in public/images in express generator folder and it will not render on the browser.

If I replace the code with `img src="http://localhost:8080/images/pic..."` it will render.

I tried every trick out there. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a base URL that the angular app would hit in order to fetch static content or hit APIs.

Hence, you might do something like below in your **service** and provide that in your **component's .ts** file or if you wish you may as well declare the **baseUrl** inside **environment.ts** file:-

```
const baseUrl = http://localhost:8080;
```

and then in your **component's HTML**:-

```
<img src="{{baseUrl}}/images/pic.png">
```

---

The problem that you face is due to `img src="/images/pic.png"`. It will hit the domain from where the angular app is served. Hence, if you are developing the app, then it will result in `img src="http://localhost:4200/images/pic.png"` generally.

However, if you serve the app from the same domain where your images are hosted, i.e. if you might have used a reverse proxy, then it is possible to fetch it the way you are trying. But that would require you to configure additional servers.

Comment: Your answer was helpful, i created a ts file with the base url localhost.. and imported into app.module. This works for when i want to insert a single image, i can use {{baseUrl}}, but what can i do when i want to construct a carousel so i want to indicate the source of the images ? The carousel images are in /public/images/carousel

Comment: @gxg  baseUrl refers only to the domain. You can prepend that inside your source tag. So, it becomes {{baseUrl}}/public/images/carousel. Let me know if i am unable to understand what you meant to say.

Comment: I succeeded just by assigning to every image in the carousel src {{baseUrl}/images/carousel/img1 etc. How can i create in the .ts file a variable named images so i can iterate in the .html. Example: "let img for images" so i can construct the carousel easier ?

Comment: @gxg - With regard to the array, then you can create an array by appending `baseUrl` with `/images/carousel/img` and then appending probably `index+1` (only if the images follow naming convention such as `img1`, `img2`, `img3`, etc.) inside your `*ngFor`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check angular settings for baseurl, such as if your running angular 4+ project you can set base url inside your index.html head tag

```
<base href="./">
```

Then you don't have to set the absolute path to any of your resources.